# How to allow Joomla users to create / update own list and have menu link to that list?

Tags: user-input, joomla2.5

I have a Joomla site I am developing that centers around designer handbags of a particular label
(not my site, it's a client's). It is not an ecommerce site, more of a social site.

What I am looking to do is present the user with a list of handbag styles and patterns so that
they can mark which items they have and which items they need.

Then two sections of content would be generated - one listing what they have and one listing what
they need.

I would also need to be able to include a direct menu link to that page.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do that would be to extend either [community builder](http://www.joomlapolis.com/) or [JomSocial](http://www.jomsocial.com/). Both have the ability to have custom user profiles which would go a long way to creating what you are looking for. You may even be able to do everything you want within the basic structure of one of those extensions.